# Removing character from dataframe

Tags: r

I have this simple code, which generates a data frame. I want to remove the `V` character from the middle column. Is there any simple way to do that?

Here is a test code (the actual code is very long), very similar with the actual code.

```
mat1=matrix(c(1,2,3,4,5,"V1","V2","V3","V4","V5",1,2,3,4,5), ncol=3)
mat=as.data.frame(mat1)
colnames(mat)=c("x","row","y")
mat
```

This is the data frame:

```
 x row y
1 1  V1 1
2 2  V2 2
3 3  V3 3
4 4  V4 4
5 5  V5 5
```

I just want to remove the `V`'s like this:

```
  x row y
1 1   1 1
2 2   2 2
3 3   3 3
4 4   4 4
5 5   5 5
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `str_replace` from `stringr`

```
library(stringr)
mat$row <- str_replace(mat$row, "V", "")
```